# how to call python class list objects

Tags: list, class, object, python-2.7

```
class Ship:

    def __init__(self, pos, vel, angle, image, info):
        self.pos = [pos[0],pos[1]]
        self.vel = [vel[0],vel[1]]


def keydown(key):

    global current_key

    current_key=simplegui.KEY_MAP['down']

    pos_increment=15
    posx=Ship.shipx
    posy=Ship.shipy

    print current_key
    print posx,posy
```

Error is AttributeError: 'Ship' object has no attribute 'shipx'.Please help

Comment: Please provide more code of the ship class. Where are shipx and shipy defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to instantiate your class before:

```
ship1 = Ship( pos, vel, angle, image, info)
```

After that you can use the class methods and attributes:

```
posx, posy = ship1.pos
```

From the our comments I think this would fit your needs:

```
class Ship:

    def __init__(self, pos, vel, angle, image, info):
        self.pos = list(pos)
        self.vel = list(vel)

    def move(self, key):
        if key=='left':  self.pos[0] -= self.vel[0]
        if key=='right': self.pos[0] += self.vel[0]
        if key=='down':  self.pos[1] -= self.vel[1]
        if key=='up':    self.pos[1] += self.vel[1]


#example
ship1 = Ship( (0,0), (10,10), angle=None, image=None, info='')

def keystroke(key):
    global current_key
    ship1.move(key)
```

I am not sure how does `simplegui` works, but in this way you can efficiently map all the keystroke possibilities. Also, it is assuming that the velocity (`vel`) is telling how many pixels to change for each keystroke.

Comment: `shipx` and `shipy` are never defined for either `Ship` or its instances, but that's either an oversight in the question or a separate question altogether.

Comment: do you mean they are class attributes?

Comment: keydown is a function outside the class Ship

Comment: @bama, ok this is clear, but for me it was not clear what you intented to do with `shipx` and `shipy`

Comment: I have to change the pos[] values when i press the keydown or keyup

Comment: @bama in this case you can do something like: `ship1.pos[0] += 1` for adding 1 to the `x` position, and `ship1.pos[1] += 1` for adding 1 to the `y` position...

Comment: when i give this in the function it is giving an error NameError: name 'pos' is not defined  ship1 = Ship( pos, vel, angle, image, info)

Comment: check if pos and vel have two fields, like (0,0), or (1,1)

Comment: can i create a function inside the class Ship. def __init__(self):
         pass

Answer (score 1):

You have to define shipx and shipy first before accessing them or use the pos variable instead:

```
class Ship:
    def __init__(self, pos, vel, angle, image, info):
        self.pos = pos
        self.vel = vel

# create instance of your ship
ship = Ship(pos, vel, angle, image, info)

def keydown(key):
    global current_key

    current_key = simplegui.KEY_MAP['down']

    pos_increment = 15
    # change y-position of the ship on key press
    ship.pos[1] += pos_increment
```

Comment: I have to change the pos[] values when i press the keydown or keyup .pos is list in the Ship class.I have to update the value by 10 pixels everytime i click the keydown or keyup